# Azure DevOps 10MB Secure files alternative

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-build

I must integrate a 3rd party module into our containerized Docker solution. On my local dev it works well as I can download the image 3rdParty_file_name.tar on the disk and use it:

```
docker load --input .\3rdParty_file_name.tar
```

The problem appears when I have to do the same in Azure Devops. How can I integrate the image *3rdParty_file_name.tar* into the container build pipeline? I can't upload the image because there's a limitation of 10MB in the Azure DevOps\Library\Secure files feature.

Comment: Since you're building containers, could you upload a container with the tar file and then use a multi-stage build to pull it in?

Comment: @erik258 Where should I upload the container?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/container-registry/ seems like an obvious choice, but anywhere you're authorized to access should work.   A public registry would probably be okay if the tar file isn't private /copyrighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure Storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview) is a good approach to remove the limitation of 10MB file size.

[image]

1.Upload your .tar to the container.

[image]

2.In your Azure Pipeline, you could use Azure CLI task to execute the [az storage blob download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download) command.

[image]

[image]

Script sample:

```
mkdir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\BlobFile
az storage blob download --container-name $(containername) --file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\BlobFile\"sample.tar" --name "sample.tar"--account-key $(accountkey) --account-name $(accountname)
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\BlobFile
ls
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, will pay attention to this.

Answer (score 0):

The other option with 0 cost was to upload the .tar file on an internal server, expose the public IP and use the Invoke-WebRequest command into the pipeline:

> ```
> - task: PowerShell@2
>   displayName:  Downloading {{imageName}} from {{serverName}}
>   inputs:
>     targetType: 'inline'
>     script:  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://websitename.ch/path/to/the/file/3rdParty_file_name.tar' -OutFile '.\3rdParty_file_name.tar' -UseBasicParsing -Credential (New-Object PSCredential('$(serverUsername)', (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String'$(serverPassword)')))
> ```